# Calculating Young's Modulus through Stress/Extension Length graph

Tags: material-science, elasticity

[Young's Modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_modulus) (Y.M.) is Stress/Strain, or the gradient of a stress vs. strain graph. We have been provided with a stress/extension length graph, and are asked to calculate the Y.M. of the material.

I have calculated all required values such as stress, strain, force and area, but how do we calculate Y.M. directly via the stress/extension length graph?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a plot of force as a function of extension length, and you have the slope of that graph, then the YM is just a scale factor away. You can do one of two things:

1. Draw a second graph, but now you plot stress as a function of strain (scaling each axis appropriately), or
2. Just multiply the slope by the appropriate scale factor.

You said you were able to convert extension to strain (extension / original length), and force to stress (force / area). Then you have all you need to do either (1) or (2) above. Since the question explicitly stated to do this from the stress/extension graph, I think you need to use method (2).